# Jquery UI Dialog and inner links & texts are not selectable / clickable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have got a problem with Jquery UI dialog window. I am loading external content in dialog window and opening it. Everything is working perfectly except 1 thing.

If I want to select texts inside the dialog window I can't select any. If I click on the links, nothing happens as if whatever inside of the dialog window is somehow blocked.

Is there anyway around this problem?

Thank you for your time and concern in advance.

Comment: Could you post some code that demonstrates this? Maybe a jsfiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: That would be quite hard. Considering the problem is happening in admin panel.

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555836/jquery-ui-selectable-links-not-being-followed-on-click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without seeing any code, my first guess would be to check your css. use firebug and make sure that any of the following styles:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

are not being applied to your text. another possible thing might be a problem with z-index. take a look at your css and see if any z-index styles are being applied, and play with them (either make them high if they are low, or make them low if they are high) to see if that fixes your problem.

another issue might be your version of jquery and jquery ui. make sure they are updated to the latest version.

Comment: I also thought of CSS. When I don't use classes it seems it is clickable.

Comment: Yes it was CSS indeed. One of my main wrapper had `z-index:400;` it was enough to add `style="z-index:0;"`. Thank you for your time.